# A node in a 2-hub neighborhood of a node has zero degree?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I have a `networkx` graph `G` and I computed the nodes that are 2-hubs away from a particular node using this code:

```
def node_neighborhood(G, node, n=2):
    """
    Returns a list of nodes which are the n-neighborhood of the input node.

    Parameters
    ----------
    G: networkx graph object.
    node: the node to get the neighborhood for.
    n: the neighborhood degree.
    """
    path_lengths = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(G, node)
    return [node for node, length in path_lengths.iteritems()
                    if length == n]
```

so this code returns the nodes are that are 2-hubs away from the specified node.

Next I removed from `G` all nodes that are NOT in the returned list from `node_neighborhood` using this code:

```
            for n in G.nodes():
                if (n not in node_2_neiborhood) and (n != node):
                    G.remove_node(n)
                else:
                    if G.degree(n) == 0:
                        raise Exception("a node has zero degree!!!")
```

However the problem is that the exception that a node has zero degree gets thrown. My question is why is that? If a node is 2-hubs away from X, then that node *must* have at least one edge! So how is it possible that a node in the neighborhood has a zero degree?!

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is so normal and expected, since with that approach I'm removing the nodes that are 1-hub away from the target node. So I'm removing the paths between the 2-hubs away nodes and the target node.